# Convert character month column into year-month format in R

Tags: r

Given a dataframe as follows:

```
Month Season Boys Girls
September   Autumn  30132   28608   
October Autumn  29985   28605   
November    Autumn  28701   27400   
December    Winter  28079   26634   
January Winter  28758   27415   
February    Winter  24745   24047   
March   Spring  27848   26027   
April   Spring  27097   25542   
May Spring  29190   27409   
June    Summer  28266   26702
```

How can I convert `Month` column into `Year-month` format, the new dataframe will like this:

```
Month Season Boys Girls
2018-09 Autumn  30132   28608   
2018-10 Autumn  29985   28605   
2018-11 Autumn  28701   27400   
2018-12 Winter  28079   26634   
2019-01 Winter  28758   27415   
2019-02 Winter  24745   24047   
2019-03 Spring  27848   26027   
2019-04 Spring  27097   25542   
2019-05 Spring  29190   27409   
2019-06 Summer  28266   26702
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where does the year information come from?

Comment: It's from text description, we can't find in data.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the text description? Otherwise there's no way we can help since we have no information about the year.

Comment: And that's the source of my question.  What is the text description?  Is the assumption that it just starts at 2018?

Comment: "The data are the number of live births for Boys and Girls in the UK between September 2018 and June 2019."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how many years your data set has. Solution for two years using `match` with built-in `month.name` (depends on locale) and `ISOdate`:

```
m <- match(dat$Month, month.name)
dat <- transform(dat, Month=strftime(ISOdate(2018+((m - m[1]) < 0), m, 1), "%Y-%m"))
dat
#      Month Season  Boys Girls
# 1  2018-09 Autumn 30132 28608
# 2  2018-10 Autumn 29985 28605
# 3  2018-11 Autumn 28701 27400
# 4  2018-12 Winter 28079 26634
# 5  2019-01 Winter 28758 27415
# 6  2019-02 Winter 24745 24047
# 7  2019-03 Spring 27848 26027
# 8  2019-04 Spring 27097 25542
# 9  2019-05 Spring 29190 27409
# 10 2019-06 Summer 28266 26702
```

---

*Data*

```
dat <- read.table(text="Month Season Boys Girls
September   Autumn  30132   28608   
October Autumn  29985   28605   
November    Autumn  28701   27400   
December    Winter  28079   26634   
January Winter  28758   27415   
February    Winter  24745   24047   
March   Spring  27848   26027   
April   Spring  27097   25542   
May Spring  29190   27409   
June    Summer  28266   26702", header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there's no year information this just generates a new month for each row in the dataframe.  It does produce the requested output, but due to the missing information isn't terribly programmatic.

```
library(dplyr)    
df %>%
      mutate(Month = format(seq(
        as.Date("2018/09/01"),
        by = "month",
        length.out = length(df$Month)
      ), "%Y-%m"))
   Month   Season  Boys Girls
   <chr>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2018-09 Autumn 30132 28608
 2 2018-10 Autumn 29985 28605
 3 2018-11 Autumn 28701 27400
 4 2018-12 Winter 28079 26634
 5 2019-01 Winter 28758 27415
 6 2019-02 Winter 24745 24047
 7 2019-03 Spring 27848 26027
 8 2019-04 Spring 27097 25542
 9 2019-05 Spring 29190 27409
10 2019-06 Summer 28266 26702
```